# Electron desktopCapturer.getSources().then is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron, getusermedia

Developing an electron application on Windows 10 Pro version 1809. Our application has a browser window the renders when the user hits a hotkey combination. The browser window calls 'renderer.js'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Audio Visualizer</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Content -->

    <script>
      require('./renderer.js')
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The `renderer.js` file handles interactions from the user within that browser window and attempts to capture user's audio using `desktopCapturer` using the screen (entire screen) as the source.

I followed the documentation on electron docs, but we're getting an error `desktopCapturer.getSources().then is not a function`

This is the `renderer.js` file

```
desktopCapturer.getSources({ types: ['window', 'screen'] }).then(async sources => {
  for (const source of sources) {
    if (source.name === 'Electron') {
      try {
        const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
          audio: {
            mandatory: {
             chromeMediaSource: 'desktop',
             chromeMediaSourceId: source.id 
            }
          },
          video: false
        })
        handleStream(stream)
      } catch (e) {
        handleError(e)
      }
      return
    }
  }
})

function handleStream (stream) {
  // create audio context and show audio visulaizaio
}

function handleError (e) {
  console.log(e)
}
```

Our code is basically a direct copy/paste from the example included in the electron docs. What are we missing that we are getting this error?

I know there is a limitation on macOS that you have to create a stream in a different what (rather than navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia), but I don't think that limitation has anything to do with this error we're facing.

Comment: What version of Electron and Node are you using?

Comment: Like Cory indicated, the docs show the *latest* documentation, but you're probably on an older Electron version that doesn't yet support the promise version of `getSources`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I overlooked that.